# Issue converting web app to Firefox OS app

Tags: firefox, operating-system

I currently have a webapp that is built using angular.js,firebase and bootstrap. I am in the process of releasing it to the Firefox app marketplace for Firefox OS devices. I have added my manifest.webapp, have set the whitelisting in angular.js that is necessary for Firefox OS. While testing in the Firefox OS simulator I get my Dom, but it is unstyled and none of the functionality works, ie none of my buttons work and there is no functionality, it simply displays unstyled HTML elements. When I  check the console while debugging there are no errors logged. Is this due to the fact that I'm getting angularjs, bootstrap and firebase through CDN?

Comment: I can provide my code if needed to clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefuly security policies in Firefox OS. If the app is packaged you should actually include angular, firebase and other libraries in it.